# How to read the value of the radio button

Tags: jsf, seam, richfaces

I would like to read the selected role information on form submit (a role is selected for a user from a list of roles). How do I read the selected radio button value in my EntityHome interface (Note: I didn't want to use the h:selectOneRadio option here)

```
                                <tr>
                                    <s:div rendered="#{userHome.instance.type ne 'admin'}">
                                        <th width="150" class="rich-table-subheadercell center">#{_user.getName()}</th>
                                    </s:div>


                                    <c:forEach items="#{userHome.instance.roles}" var="_role">
                                        <td width="150" class="center" style="background: rgb(100, 100, 100) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">
                                            #{_role.name}
                                            <input type="radio" style="display : none" name="#{userHome.instance.id}" value="#{_role.id}"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </tr>
```

Comment: This ain't going to work seamlessly. Please elaborate **why** you don't want to use `h:selectOneRadio` (or any other JSF component). How was it insufficient for your requirements? If you elaborate more about the insufficiency *and* the functional requirements, we may be able to provide the right solution/workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Two comments.

First of all. Use JSF Components where you can.

Secondly. Avoid using JSTL tags. Remove the `c:forEach` if you don't have to use it. Replace it with `ui:repeat`, `h:dataTable` etc.

Now to answer your question for a workaround if you can't directly use `h:selectOneRadio`

What you will have to do is use `@WebRemote` in Seam, and then by using javascript you can on form submit, set the value through Ajax in your `UserHome` component.

Take a look at chapter [5. Remoting](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.1.CR1/reference/en-US/html/remoting.html) in the Seam Documentation for more information on how to use Remoting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to point the value / list to an ArrayList of SelectItem there's where the items you selected will be stored.

Comment: Have you checked the code and read the question? How would you do this that way without `h:selectOneRadio`?

Comment: I just pointed out that he need to use a List to store the values selected.

Comment: This is just plain wrong. OP want's one value, thus you should point the value, in this case role to either `Role` or `String` and not `List` as you imply here. If there was a checkbox, then `List` would have been correct